# TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

Can anyone tell me what is the error in my code. I couldn't find out my error___________________________________________________________________________

```
router.get('/:filename', (req,res) => {
    const img = req.params.filename; // Filename
    gfs.collection('wdress').findOne({filename: img}, (req,file) => {
        if(req.session.name==null) {
            req.session.name = [{
                brand: img
            }]
        } else {
            req.session.name.push({
                brand: img
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of null
  at gfs.collection.findOne (M:\FinalProject\Commerce\routes\index.js:186:8)
 at result 
 (M:\FinalProject\Commerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:414:17)
```

app.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.locals.items = req.session;
 next();
});
```

Comment: yes, i already initialized those :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this callback

```
gfs.collection('wdress').findOne({filename: img}, (req,file) => {
```

should accept the first parameter as `error`.

```
gfs.collection('wdress').findOne({filename: img}, (error,file) => {
```

And you've got `error = null` in the callback and `req` is overlapping with another `req` from the higher scope `(req,res)`. Looks like this was a copy/paste typo.

Comment: Moral of the story: indent the code, and never copy-paste. ;)